# Dependency injection - named dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, light-inject

I'm dealing with one problem. Imagine this example situation. I have one module e.g. UserModule with injected IUserRepository. IUserRepository can have more implementations e.g. IUserRepositorySql and IUserRepositoryDefault.

```
public class UserModule : IUserModule
{
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

    public UserModule(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        if (userRepository == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("userRepository");
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
}
```

I would like to define which implementation of IUserRepository will be used in UserModule. I want to avoid Factory pattern that is considered like IoC antipattern in [Marc Seeman book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) and I would like achieve this only with container configuration.

I'm using LightInject and it has something like [named services](http://www.lightinject.net/#toc4) but it can be used only on the top level. I need something like this :

```
var container = new ServiceContainer();

container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepositorySql>("Sql");
container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepositoryDefault>("Default");
container.Register<IUserModule, UserModule>();

var instance = container.GetInstance<IUserModule>("Sql");
```

This code should return instance of IUserModule with injected UserRepositorySql instance, but of course, it doesn't.

**Do you have some soulution for this in LightInject please?**

I found a feature [annotation in Lightinject](http://www.lightinject.net/#annotation) where I can inject some properties of an appropriate types, but I don't like this solution so much.

**Do you have any experience in some other IoC containers? How do you/which feature does solve this issue?**

Comment: I've read Mark Seemann's book, but can't recall he calling Factory an anti-pattern. Can you refer to the pages where he does so?

Comment: Can you explain why you actually need to be able to do this?

Comment: I know that Mark Seemann considers the Service Locator to be an anti pattern (http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), so that's how I read this question.

Comment: @Steven in chapter about anti-patterns you can find Control Freak anti-pattern. As an examples, Mark Seeman gave factory patterns (you have to use new keyword)

Comment: @Steven this is only simplified example. I need it because I need dynamically use other modules for some types of service calls.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted that chapter. Mark doesn't call Factories an anti-pattern. On page 139 he even says: "Abstract Factory is [...] useful in relation to DI because it can encapsulate complex logic that creates other DEPENDENCIES. It offers a good alternative to the complete transfer of control that's involved in full INVERSION OF CONTROL".

Comment: @Steven Yes you're right. Mark Seeman wrote that control freak is occurred very often in factory pattern but it is possible to implement factory in clean way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to agree both with Steven and Astrotrain here, but there is a third option available.

The following example uses parameters to resolve the correct implementation of the IUserRepository interface.

```
using LightInject;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new ServiceContainer();
        container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepositorySql>("Sql");
        container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepositoryDefault>("Default");
        container.Register<string, IUserModule>(
            (factory, serviceName) => new UserModule(factory.GetInstance<IUserRepository>(serviceName)));

        var userModuleWithSqlRepository = container.GetInstance<string, IUserModule>("Sql");
        var userModuleWithDefaultRepository = container.GetInstance<string, IUserModule>("Default");
    }
}

public interface IUserModule { }

public class UserModule : IUserModule
{
    public UserModule(IUserRepository repository)
    {
    }
}

public interface IUserRepository { }

public class UserRepositorySql : IUserRepository { }

public class UserRepositoryDefault : IUserRepository { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that Unity supports specifying which named instance to use when performing
constructor injection by means of the [ResolvedParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee650275.aspx) class (which works just
like your imaginary construction):

```
container.Register<IUserModule, UserModule>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IUserModule>("Sql")));
```

However, most DI frameworks also support factory methods, and the above example
could also be written in Unity as:

```
container.Register<IUserModule>(
    new InjectionFactory(cont => cont.Resolve<IUserModule>("Sql"));
```

In this case, you tell Unity that you want it to use your expression whenever
it should create an IUserModule instance, and in that expression, you're free 
to use the container to resolve a specific instance.

I suspect that the latter construction could very well be possible with your DI
framework as well.